# PHP Equivalent to strtotime() in GO

Tags: go

I am trying to convert date/time string to unix timestamp string:

```
<?php
    echo strtotime("20140921040000");
?>
Output: 1411286400   //timestamp
```

Doing same in GO lang, but not getting desired result.
Go code is below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tm := time.Unix(1411286400, 0)
    fmt.Println(tm) //output: 2014-09-21 08:00:00 +0000 UTC

    //================
    layout := "20060102150405"
    str := "20140921040000"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t) // output: 2014-09-21 04:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your last line do:

```
fmt.Println(t.Unix())
```

You can compare it with this PHP code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b520953ea26e2d84ed85db6f5657ceeccade08d4

Comment: But, it is not same as php strtotime(). Both output are different. And output of php function is correct.

Comment: Actually, your PHP is wrong, as it probably uses server locale. Plese see PHP code example above.

Comment: @Daisy Indeed, from [the documentation](http://php.net/strtotime): `Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended`.